# BSD nc (netcat) does not terminate on EOF

Tags: networking, freebsd, bsd, nc

Host A:

```
tar cf -  stuff | dd | nc  -N -l 12987
```

Host B:

```
nc a.example.com 12987 | dd | tar tf -
```

On host A `dd` prints its summary after `tar` completes. Thus it is clear, that tar closes the pipe/file -> `EOF`.

> 165040+0 records in 165040+0 records out 84500480 bytes transferred in
>   25.464802 secs (3318325 bytes/sec)

On both hosts `nc` happily sits there without exiting. 
`nc(1)` :

```
   -N      shutdown(2) the network socket after EOF on the input.  Some
           servers require this to finish their work.
```

Thus on host A `nc` should have seen `EOF`, closed the damn socket and on host B `nc` should have seen the TCP connection terminate and should have closed `stdout` (`stdin` of `dd`/`tar`).

**How do I tell `nc` to close `stdout` / terminate on host B and terminate on host A**.

`nc` bug?

`-D` (debug) does nothing. `nc` can't even tell its version number... *sigh*

Both hosts are *FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p4*, IPv4 only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I, too, was puzzled by netcat's behavior, so I dug into the code. Here's the whole story:

nc servers (`nc -l`) and clients only exit after the mutual connection was closed. That is, if each of the parties sent a [FIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination) packet to the other party.

A server always sends a `FIN` packet after receiving a `FIN` packet from the client. (Unless the server already sent a `FIN` packet.)

A client sends a FIN packet either:

- after `EOF` on stdin, when run with argument `-N`
- after `EOF` on stdin, when the server already sent a FIN packet

With option `-d`  stdin is ignored and `nc` behaves as if it encountered `EOF` on stdin.

Option `-N` always implies sending `FIN` after encountering `EOF` on stdin.

#### Ways to exit the nc processes after exchanging data:

1. Georg's answer

   ```
    server$ echo hello | nc -l -N 2000
    client$ nc -d localhost 2000
   ```

   After sending `hello`, the server encounters `EOF` on stdin an sends `FIN` because of `-N`.

   The client receives the message and, due to `-d`, sees `EOF` on stdin and sends `FIN`, because the server already sent `FIN`.

   The connection is closed, both the client and the server exit.
2. Client initiates the close

   ```
    server$ echo hello | nc -l 2000
    client$ nc -dN localhost 2000
   ```

   The server keeps the connection open after `EOF` on stdin.

   The client sees `EOF` on stdin and sends `FIN`, because of `-N`.

   The server sends `FIN` after receiving the client's `FIN`.

   The connection is closed, both the client and the server exit.

Comment: Thank you. But you answer (2.) problematic. If server run `(echo hello; sleep 5; echo world;) | nc -l 2000`, client will only receive `hello` and close TCP with FIN, `world` will **not** be received. I have tried it on openSUSE 15.1.

Answer (score 5):

`nc` establishes a **bi-directional** connection. I.e. it sends `stdin` from host B to host A as well as the desired one from A to B.

Use `-d` on host B to ignore `stdin`. `-N` on host A is still needed to close the `TCP` connection on EOF.

---

In summary

Host A:

```
tar cf -  stuff | dd | nc  -N -l 12987
```

Host B:

```
nc -d a.example.com 12987 | dd | tar tf -
```